# Increment a value regarding a pattern in a file

Tags: shell

I have a file like this :

```
"A";"1"
"A";""
"A";""
"B";"1"
"C";"1"
"C";""
"C";""
```

When I have the same pattern between first part of current line and previous line, I want increment the second part of my line.
like this :

```
"A";"1"
"A";"2"
"A";"3"
"B";"1"
"C";"1"
"C";"2"
"C";"3"
```

or if second part is empty I take the previous line and I increment it.

Do you have any idea how I can do this with a shell script or maybe with awk or sed command?

Comment: You should also have a "A";"3", haven't you?

Comment: exact, I correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With perl:

```
$ perl -F';' -lane 'if ($F[1] =~ /"(\d+)"/) { $saved = $1; } else { $saved++; $F[1] = qq/"$saved"/; }
   print join(";", @F)' example.txt 
"A";"1"
"A";"2"
"A";"3"
"B";"1"
"C";"1"
"C";"2"
"C";"3"
```

With awk:

```
$ awk -F';' -v OFS=';' '
   $2 ~ /"[0-9]+"/ { saved = substr($2, 2, length($2) - 2) }
   $2 == "\"\"" { $2 = "\"" ++saved "\"" }
   { print }' example.txt
"A";"1"
"A";"2"
"A";"3"
"B";"1"
"C";"1"
"C";"2"
"C";"3"
```

Comment: Thank you it's working. I try to understand the awk command and specifically where we restart to 1 your incrementing. I guess it’s on the saved variable...

Comment: @Maxime If the second field matches the regular expression `"[0-9]+"` (A number surrounded by quotes), that number is used as the new value to start counting from for the next empty field.